# Integrating a function in a circle region, not converging to the value in the center

Tags: python, numerical-integration

I have a function, let's call it `u(x,y)`. I do not have an explicit formula for it, at the moment, as it is defined from a bunch of other functions, but it uses only arithmetic and trigonometric operations, so I am expecting continuity and all those good properties.

I was trying to use a numeric method to calculate the average (by dividing the integral by the area of the region) of `u` in a circle, given its center and radius, as well as in a square, given, again, its center and side.

Here is the code I am currently using (Python):

```
# Integral in a column, x constant, y in ]y_c - l/2, y_c + l/2[, using n points:
def F(x, y_c, l, n):
    def f(b):
        return u(x,b)

    h = l / n

    y0 = y_c - l / 2
    yn = y_c + l / 2
    s = 0

    for i in range(1, n):
        yi = y0 + h * i
        s += f(yi)

    return h * (f(y0) + f(yn)) / 2 + h * s


# Integral in the circle of center (x_c, y_c) and radius r, using aprox n points:
def int_circ(x_c, y_c, r, n):
    def f(x, l):
        return F(x, y_c, l, int(np.sqrt(n)))

    h = 2 * r / np.sqrt(n)
    x0 = x_c - r
    xn = x_c + r
    s = 0

    for i in range(1, int(np.sqrt(n))):
        xi = x0 + h * i
        li = 2 * np.sqrt(r ** 2 - (xi - x_c) ** 2)
        s += f(xi, li)

    l = 2 * np.sqrt(r ** 2 - (r - h / 4) ** 2)

    return h / 2 * (f(x0 + h / 2, l) + f(xn - h / 2, l)) + h * s


# Integral in the square of center (x_c, y_c) and side 2r, using aprox n points:
def int_sqr(x_c, y_c, r, n):
    def f(x):
        return F(x, y_c, 2 * r, int(np.sqrt(n)))

    h = 2 * r / np.sqrt(n)
    x0 = x_c - r
    xn = x_c + r
    s = 0

    for i in range(1, int(np.sqrt(n))):
        xi = x0 + h * i
        s += f(xi)

    return h * (f(x0) + f(xn)) / 2 + h * s
```

When analyzing the results, I could see that when I reduced the side of the square, it was approaching the value of the function in the center, as expected. However, with the circle, it converged to a different value, with around `10^-4` of relative error, over the expected, for n=10000. The problem persisted when I replaced `u` with the constant function =1. ´

Note: increasing n does make for a better approximation, but it seems to me like there should be a better way of doing this.

I had tried a few different algorithms for the circle integral, and all seemed to fail in the same way, and I recognized that some area inside the circle was not being taken into account, or that some area outside of the circle was being taken into account. This one was the closest.

How can I make it approach the value of the center better?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to [so]. We don't provide general debugging services. We can assist with specific issues. Please use the following references on debugging your code to narrow your problem to a specific issue. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), [Six Debugging Techniques for Python Programmers](https://medium.com/techtofreedom/six-debugging-techniques-for-python-programmers-cb25a4baaf4b)

Comment: `u` is not defined.  also need to `import numpy as np`.

Comment: I didn't include the definition for u on purpose as it would take up a lot of space and doesn't impact the results, since even when I put `def u(x,y): return 1`, the integral of the circle (after dividing by the area) isn't perfect, while the square one is. The focus was meant to be the integration algorithm.
I apologize for forgetting to mention the numpy shorthand.